# Java set variables to a same value or function

Tags: java, android

Hello I have a some variables that I want to perform a same function to all of them like this:

```
var1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
var2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
var3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Is there any way to set them together like this?

```
(var1&var2&var3).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: No, but if you have a collection instead of separate variables, you could use `for (Foo foo : foos) { foo.setVisibility(View.GONE); }`

Comment: Sorry but I'm totally new in java I didn't catch what u say. Can you explain more?

Comment: You should use a collection or an array, probably. It's hard to tell without more context though.

Answer (score 1):

To create a custom method accepting `varargs` could be an option

```
void setViewOfVar(View view, Var ... vars) {
    for (Var v : vars) v.setVisibility(view);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to do such a thing in java. However, you can store your vars in a list and then iterate over the list to do something like

for(MyVar var : vars)  {
        var.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can use Stream API for that:

```
Stream.of(var1, var2, var3).forEach(v -> v.setVisibility(View.GONE));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one such option that you can do to achieve your requirements.

You need to use a [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) library that will bind the field and method with Android views.

### You can group multiple views into a List or array.

```
@BindViews({ R.id.first_name, R.id.middle_name, R.id.last_name })
List<EditText> nameViews;
```

### The apply method allows you to act on all the views in a list at once.

```
ButterKnife.apply(nameViews, DISABLE);
```